# Pandas DataFrame Issue. Don't know how to clean and manage a sort of block matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

here is my first question: I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like the following:

[Pandas Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFfOE.png)

The DataFrame shown in the picture is simplified (its original shape is `[1195674 x 11])` but it doesn't matter.

I am trying to set the left hand side `(columns A, B, C, D)` as index and the right hand side `(columns E, F, G)` as corresponding values (look at the colors).

Do you have any hint?

P.S. another way could be to replicate the left hand side `(rows)` in order to have something like the following (the red rows should be cancelled out):

[Second Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MSkG.png)

Can you propose any other way to accomplish this task?

Many thanks in advance!

Franco

Comment: `df[['A','B','C','D']] = df[['A','B','C','D']].ffill()` ?

Comment: Hi Scott, can you provide a more precise answer? Thank you!

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are looking for.   ffill() will fill na's with the previous value above the NaN.

Comment: Many thanks Scott! That's what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `ffill`, which will fill forward values for NaN:

```
df[['A','B','C','D']] = df[['A','B','C','D']].ffill()
```